# send large int[] array from java android client, to c# server

Tags: java, c#, android, arrays

I've sent a string and images from Java Android to a C# server. But I'm having a problem with the integer array.

**Is it a good logic to use `dataOutputStream.writeByte(Array[i])` inside a `for` loop (Client side)?**

I've tested with a small array of 6 elements only. In the server, the array elements are received but not the same numbers as in client array. Why is that?

OUTPUT:

```
client array : (1,3333,50,6,7,8}
server array : {37, 37, 9, 45, 18, 18}!!
```

Client Android:

```
public void ConnectToServer()
{
    //generate array with random numbers
    int[] array = {1,333,5,60,7,8};

    try {

        //Connect to socket
        Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       for(int i=0; i< 6; i++)
       {  outToServer.writeByte(array[i]);}

         outToServer.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        Log.e("MESSAGE", "array sent Successfully");

        //receive msg from (server)
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //for reading response from server
       recievedMsg =  r.readLine();

        //clean
        r.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.3");client
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAdress, 4003);
                listener.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Server Waiting for connections...");
                Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
                // When accepted
                NetworkStream nstm = new NetworkStream(s);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(nstm);
                byte result;
                int number;

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {  result = reader.ReadByte();
                    number = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() + "---"+ i);
                }

               //send the response to client
                Byte[] sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("received !");
                nstm.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                    //Clean up
                    s.Close();
                    listener.Stop();
             }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.....CL1 " + e.Message + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

java use big endian, and c# use little endian.

Comment: so, how can i deal with this ?

Comment: @k-s-b change `{  outToServer.writeByte(array[i]);}` to `{  outToServer.writeInt(array[i]);}`. And may need trun byte from big endian to little endian in your server

Comment: ok in the client if i wrote `outToServer.WriteByte(array[i])` and in the server `int number = binaryReader.readInt16()` the results receive correct as sent EXCEPT 3333 recevied 5 ??? Why?

Comment: @k-s-b writeByte(array[i]) will cast int to byte, if int > 127, int will be 127. Also int = 4 byte. wirteByte(array[i]) only write 1byte. if you want to write int, you should use writeInt(array[i]) or change int to byte[4].

Comment: ok thank you, Now i will use`outToServer.writeInt(array[i]);` in the client...please how can i received in server correctly?

Comment: For example, 0x12345678, big endian order is 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78, little endian order is 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12.

Comment: mmm.. u said "change int to byte[4]" what do mean by that?

Comment: int i = 1; byte[] data = new byte[4]; data[0] = (byte)(i&0xFF); data[1] = (byte)((i >> 8)&0xFF); data[2] = (byte)((i >> 16)&0xFF); data[3] = (byte)((i >> 24)&0xFF)